# Enviar e receber variável para outra página

Tags: javascript

Quero enviar uma variável para outra página em JavaScript, atraves do button onclick. Consigo enviar e ver na barra de endereço o seu valor. O problema é a receber na segunda página. Exemplo:

```
var object=3;

function btn_onclick() 
{
    window.location.href = "page.htm?object="+object;
}

<input type=button value=pass  onclick="return btn_onclick()" />
```

Página 2 para receber:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   alert(object);

</script>
```

Comment: Qual é o typo da variável que queres enviar? string, object, integer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você precisa obter estas variáveis da *URL* primeiramente. Respondida esta mesma dúvida [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/1216394), na sua segunda página, você pode ter algo assim:

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

E obter o valor de `object` assim:

```
var obj = getParameterByName('object');
alert(obj);
```

Answer (score 4):

Para receber pode usar essa simples função `JavaScript` que pega a URL e decodifica ela, guardando os parâmetros dentro de um array:

```js
function urlDecode(string, overwrite){
 if(!string || !string.length){
  return {};
 }
 var obj = {};
 var pairs = string.split('&');
 var pair, name, value;
 var lsRegExp = /\+/g;
 for(var i = 0, len = pairs.length; i < len; i++){
  pair = pairs[i].split('=');
  name = unescape(pair[0]);
  value = unescape(pair[1]).replace(lsRegExp, " ");
  if(overwrite !== true){
   if(typeof obj[name] == "undefined"){
    obj[name] = value;
   }else if(typeof obj[name] == "string"){
    obj[name] = [obj[name]];
    obj[name].push(value);
   }else{
    obj[name].push(value);
   }
  }else{
   obj[name] = value;
  }
 }
 return obj;
}

var url = "www.testetestando.com?parametro1=oi&parametro2=x"; // Recebe a URL
var params = urlDecode(url.substring(url.indexOf("?")+1)); // Decodifica e monta um array com todos parametros
document.getElementById('teste').innerHTML = url+"<br/>"+params['parametro1']+"<br/>"+params['parametro2'];
```

```html
<div id="teste"></div>
```