# Escrever os dados de um inputText em outro inputText

Tags: java, primefaces, jpa

Pessoal estou usando JAVA,JPA,PrimeFaces...Em minha view (xhtml) eu tenho uma tela de login,como faço para pegar o nome que o usuario digitou e escrever em outro campo inputText?

Comment: Não é melhor usar javascript e fazer isso client-side?

Comment: Amigo, tem várias formas de fazer, mas seria interessante você postar seu código para podermos dar a resposta baseado no que você quer.

Comment: Veja se isso te ajuda:
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/54037/enviar-e-receber-vari%C3%A1vel-para-outra-p%C3%A1gina

Comment: Veja se isso te ajuda:
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/54037/enviar-e-receber-vari%C3%A1vel-para-outra-p%C3%A1gina

Comment: Carlos, agradeço o link mas nao ajdou muito pq é de um inputText, oq eu me mandou o valr esta descrito na URL o meu nao esta, quero simplesmente pegar o que esta num inputText e escrever em outro inputText de outra página

Answer (score 0):

Se for em tempo de execução (sem recarregar a pagina) o melhor é usar JQuery:

```
 <script> 
                jQuery(document).ready(function () {
                    jQuery('#idCampoOrigem').blur(function () { 
                        jQuery('#idCampoDestino').val(jQuery('#idCampoOrigem').val()); 
                    });
                });
            </script>
```

Comment: Norivan desculpe, não expliquei 100%,...realmente muda de página sim...=/
Quero o texto digitado em um campo e escrever este texto em outro campo em outra tela.

Comment: Grava a informação do primeiro campo no seu controller em escopo de sessão e pega na outra tela